# Django database query: How to get object by id?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Django automatically creates an id field as primary key.

Now I need to get the object by this id.

```
object = Class.objects.filter()
```

How to write this filter?

Answer (score 302, accepted):

If you want to get an object, using `get()` is more straightforward:

```
obj = Class.objects.get(pk=this_object_id)
```

Comment: FYI, `pk` is the preferred way to refer to the primary key for any model.  The `id` field is only generated if the model author doesn't specifically designate a primary key.  If the author *did* specify a primary key field that isn't named `id`, then there will not be an `id` field.

Comment: Also FYI, `id` in a built-in function that returns the identity of an object. In a majority of cases referencing things by `id` will do the right thing e.g. `Class.objects.get(id=this_object_id)` work. But that's something to consider I guess.

Answer (score 27):

I got here for the same problem, but for a different reason:

```
Class.objects.get(id=1)
```

This code was raising an ImportError exception. What was confusing me was that the code below executed fine and returned a result set as expected:

```
Class.objects.all()
```

Tail of the traceback for the `get()` method:

```
File "django/db/models/loading.py", line 197, in get_models
    self._populate()
File "django/db/models/loading.py", line 72, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
File "django/db/models/loading.py", line 94, in load_app
    app_module = import_module(app_name)
File "django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named myapp
```

Reading the code inside Django's `loading.py`, I came to the conclusion that my `settings.py` had a bad path to my app which contains my `Class` model definition. All I had to do was correct the path to the app and the `get()` method executed fine.

Here is my `settings.py` with the corrected path:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    # ...
    'mywebproject.myapp',
```

)

All the confusion was caused because I am using Django's ORM as a standalone, so the namespace had to reflect that.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) django shortcut. It raises a 404 error if object is not found.

Comment: neat way to do unless one does not want to explicitly handle an object not found error

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
objects_all=Class.objects.filter(filter_condition="")
```

This will return a query set even if it gets one object.
If you need exactly one object use:

```
obj=Class.objects.get(conditon="")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do:

```
obj = ClassModel.get_by_id(object_id)
```

This works, but there may I'm not sure if it's supported in Django 2.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have some id, e.g., mysite.com/something/9182301, you can use `get_object_or_404` importing by `from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404`.

Use example:

```
def myFunc(request, my_pk):
    my_var = get_object_or_404(CLASS_NAME, pk=my_pk)
```