# Query database based on id in django

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

I have the following Model in django.

```
class Choices(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    option1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    option2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    option3 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I would like to display in my template the element of option2 field with id=1.
Is there a way I can do this?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300365/django-database-query-how-to-get-object-by-id

Answer (score 0):

You should get the `Choice` inside your view and then pass it to your template. Example:

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

def my_view(request, choice_id):
    choice = get_object_or_404(Choice, id=choice_id)
    return render(request, "my_template.html", {"choice": choice}
```

**my_template.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    {{ choice.option2 }}
  </body>
</html>
```